# Help please! One factor but one item poorly correlated with others

Tags: factor-analysis

Can anyone give me a simple answer to why Parallel Analysis is telling me it is a one factor solution when one of the ten items is very weakly correlated with the others?

Comment: have you examined communalities among your items?

Comment: Welcome on CrossValidaten. You will improves your chances of good answers if you present more details (n, show parallel analysis, show correlation matrix,...) None of us knows what you consider "very weakly".